# Android view thumbnail extraction has artifacts

Tags: android

I have a custom view on which I draw bordered rectangles like so :

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas cv) {
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setStrokeWidth(5);
    p.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    for (Rect rect : rects) {
        cv.drawRect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, p);
    }
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    for (Rect rect : rects) {
        cv.drawRect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, p);
    }
}
```

When the user has modified this view by interacting with it, it is time to save it to the sqlite database, as well as a thumbnail of it, the purpose of which is to add a thumbnail of each specific view to a listview, when the user wants to retrieve a specific one.
All of this works perfectly, with the exception of the thumbnail process : some, but not all, of the black lines are lost, every other pixel is correct, and the scaling is correct too.

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap original = view.getDrawingCache();
int w = original.getWidth();
int h = original.getHeight();
float scaling = 100f / Math.max(w, h);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, Math.round(scaling * w), Math.round(scaling * h), false);
```

The bitmap is wrong at this specific point, whether it is created with the above code, with the ThumbnailUtils class, or with a android.graphic.Matrix to handle the scaling.
Without scaling, the bitmap is always right.

[image: Original canvas] [image: Scaled erroneous thumbnail] Here is a screenshot of the view, composed of four rectangles (square ones, in this case), and of the erroneous thumbnail generated by the above code.

If anyone has a lead, thanks a lot.

Comment: I figured that the smaller the size of the thumbnail, the likeliest artifacts were to happen. Still it is passing strange that only the black lines (and not all of them) disappear. The other two possible colors, grey and white, are never impacted.

Comment: I "solved" my problem by adding a convenience function that draws the same thing at a smaller scale on another canvas; this still does not explain why this happens; does anyone figure it might be a reportable android bug?